# H2 Database how to keep rows un-ordered when updated

Tags: database, sorting, h2

So I have a simple database with a table that has multiple column, most of which are of string type, one of which is a Boolean type.

My problem occurs when I update a row changing the boolean state, the database re-organizes its self to let the values with a false state be first and the values with the true state to be last in the table.

Is there a way to tell the table not to order the table either while each row is being updated or while the actual table is being created?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL databases, the order of rows within a table is usually undefined. So if you run a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

then the database engine may return the rows in any order. If you want to order the rows, you need to use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY NAME
```